# how to multiple model can use single api in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i create login api for admin, principle, teacher, student all model for single api but not supported array of findOne() function.

i am trying array through and promise.

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res){

    var anc = [admin, principle, teacher, student];

    // Promise.all([
    //     admin.findOne({email: req.body.email}),
    //     student.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    // ]).then(function(data){
    //     res.send(data)
    // }).catch(function(err){
    //     res.send(err);
    // })

    //this is not working proper 
    // if find email in admin then show admin data and student = null.

    anc.findOne({ email: req.body.email}, function(err, data){
        // console.log(data);
        //  res.send(data);

        if(err){
            next(err);
        } else {
            if(data != null && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.password)){

                const token = jwt.sign({data}, 'abcde', { expiresIn: '1h'});
                res.json({status: "success", message: "user found!!", data: {userrole: data.userrole, token: token}});
            } else{
                res.json({status:"error", message: "Invalid email/password!!!", data:null});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `anc.findOne` is an error first callback style pattern, so it will not work with `Promise.all` since it expects an array of promises.

If you want to use `Promise.all`, then you need to turn both of your database calls (`admin.findOne` & `student.findOne`) to promises.

For example:

```js
// let's assume `admin.findOne` uses an error first callback style
function adminFindOneAsPromise(params) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    admin.findOne({ email: params.email }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      resolve(data)
    })
  })
}
function studentFindOneAsPromise(params) {
  // same idea as above
}
```

Then you could use these new functions in your `Promise.all`:

```js
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  Promise.all([
    adminFindOneAsPromise({ email: req.body.email }),
    studentFindOneAsPromise({ email: req.body.email })
  ])
  .then(function(result) {
    // `result` will be an array of values that got returned
    // as a result of calling both 
    // `adminFindOneAsPromise` & `studentFindOneAsPromise`
    const [adminResult, studentResult] = result

    // ...

    res.json({ status: "success", ... })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // handle your error appropriately
    res.json({ status: "error", ... })
  })
})
```

---

Also, one thing that I want to point out is that this will not work:

```js
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  var anc = [admin, principle, teacher, student]

  // `anc` is an array, and you can't access 
  // its content with the `dot` notation
  anc.findOne(...) // is wrong

  // if you want to use the `admin`-related calls,
  // you need to use an index, so it should be
  anc[0].findOne(...)
})
```

However, I'd advise to not put these in an array because from what it looks like there's no reason for it. Just simply use:

```js
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  admin.findOne(...)
})
```